# how to scale to fit pages opened from HTML file containing web links

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, webview

I have an app I am working on in Xcode. Part of the app area loads an html file. The HTML file itself has some links to external websites. They open fine, except they are not scaled to fit on the iPhone.

How would I go about ensuring all web pages opened are scaled to fit? The code from the .m file is below

```
NSString *fileString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"chapter5" ofType: @"html"];

NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: fileString];

NSURLRequest *newURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: newURL];

[webview loadRequest: newURLRequest];
```

The HTML file "chapter5.html contains links to websites.

I thought I would try entering

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES
```

in the .m file hoping it would apply to anything opened, but that didn't work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scalesPageToFit will take effect only when the webView loads the request. Implement the delegate of UIWebView  [webViewDidFinishLoad:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) method and try this code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGSize defaultSize = webView.frame.size;
    CGSize fittingSize = [tableViewCell.webView sizeThatFits:defaultSize];
    [webView sizeThatFits:fittingSize];

    NSLog(@"Size : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(fittingSize));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set webview mode as Aspect-Fit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I set webview mode as Aspect-Fit and set the Scaling to scale pages to fit and this worked, not sure how I missed that.